# What is the purpose of the plastic lower engine cover on a Honda Fit?

Tags: honda, fit

What is the purpose of the plastic lower engine cover in a Honda Fit? Mine broke off in a minor accident.the car is now making creaking noises when I drive and the indicator lights keep going on and off, is it related? Safe to drive? Car is running well

Comment: Not only for aerodynamics but reducing the noise levels as well.

Answer (score 1):

The lower plastic covers are for aerodynamics. They aren't really needed for function, so aren't a safety item. You should be able to drive them just fine without them.

That said, if you are hearing creaking, it wouldn't be because you are missing these covers. There is something else going on which might make your car unsafe to drive. I'd have it professionally looked at, for peace of mind, if nothing else.

Comment: If it "broke off", there might be some *pieces* of the cover still flapping about in the breeze and making noises. Get rid of all of it, even if you don't plan to replace it. The indicators seem like a separate problem, but that might also have been caused by the accident, for example if some electrical connections have come loose.

Comment: Could be a better idea to keep the lower engine cover/splash cover as some engine oil filters among other components based on design may hang really low/lower on certain cars. i.e. like in certain Toyota Priuses. Components could potentially be susceptible to rocks/anything else on the road. Also the cover is pretty durable that if you were to mount onto a higher uneven road surface you'd hear it scrape, pretty good indicator to slow down etc.

Answer (score 0):

An under engine cover also protects engine sensors and the wiring loom from water and debris off the road.  It can also help route airflow created by the radiator fan.

The creaking & indicator problem might be related to a cable being stressed during the incident or another part being loose as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

My 2018's cover came back held on by two of the eight after my dealer's complimentary first oil change.   It dropped down on the Interstate.  Since then I do my own oil changes.

The cover does complicates oil changes, but I want it there for aerodynamics, protection from water and debris, and noise reduction (there's a sound absorbing panel built into the engine side of the cover).

For the DIYer the cover is tedious to remove and replace. That's why garages either fail to secure it or toss it altogether, as most owners would never notice. I recommend buying some spare clips (`91514-TG1-T01`), screws (`90114-SE0-000`), and suspension nuts (`90308-SB2-013`). (Third party non-Honda are much less expensive, work well so far for me).